# How to call a method of any Activity or pass some data to the Activity class from a View

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I triggered a new activity from a View.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullscreenActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
```

Now I wanted to pass some data from this view to Android FullscreenActivity class, may be calling some method of activity with some param or something like that.
How to do that?

I am intended to use a java Object like way , so that since I have an intent can I call any of its method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullscreenActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Description",description_tab);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

**In this "Description is a key value which you retrieve in FullScreenActivity and description_tab is the value which you want to use in the  FullScreenActivity "**

**In FullscreenActivity.java and for retrieve use this**

```
Intent descriptionIntent = getIntent();
String description_tab= descriptionIntent.getExtras().getString("Description");
```